# Where { component } from 'react' is located when we are importing ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm new in ReactJS and wants to learn a couple of small things, and here is one. I wrote an import code on App.js like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Load from './Loading.js';
```

I created a custom file for a loading animation and it's imported from `import Load from './Loading.js'`

the `'./Loading.js'` is the file name and location, and the `Load` is a const that is exported from the *Loading.js* file

> So my question is, if the `Load` is a *const* that I've been exported on the js file I've wrote, then where is the `{ Component }` from `'react'` is located? I was trying to find it on the *node_modules* folder but got no clue. even the `react.js` file that I thought it was on the *node_modules/react* folder, I couldn't find it

Thank you before!

Comment: try do press shift and click on the `Component` import

Answer (score 0):

`Component` is declared inside react library, it's located inside the node_modules inside react's folder (maybe it's hard to find because the files are minified and packed) if you are using VsCode, you can click on the component and where the cursor is pointing on it then press `F12` it will redirect you to the file where it's exactly declared.

Comment: Thank you very much, F12 will be a very useful function! It turns out it's located in \node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts :D