# How does an import from node_modules really work in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I installed **react-vis** via `npm install react-vis`
and its possible to write
`import { XYPlot, LineSeries } from 'react-vis';`

I want to know how the systems knows where XYPlot and LineSeries are? I looked in the node_modules directory and there is no index.js.

The structure of the react-vis directory is the following

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ react-vis/
│  │  ├─ dist/
│  │  ├─ es/
│  │  ├─ CHANGELOG.md
│  │  ├─ LICENSE
│  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  ├─ README.md
```

How does this work?
I researched and for example this does not helped me: [Where { component } from 'react' is located when we are importing ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016938/where-component-from-react-is-located-when-we-are-importing-reactjs)

**Edit**
I think it looks in the package.json that is inside the react-vis directory. There are two entries that look interesting. `"name": "dist"` and `"module": "es"`. I think that i have to look inside the `dist` directory. Inside the `dist` directory, there is an `index.js` file. I open this file and on line 318 it says `exports.XYPlot = _xyPlot2.default;`

In the `es` folder inside the `index.js` there is on line 98 this: `export { _XYPlot as XYPlot };` I don't know if this is important.

Comment: You've answered your question yourself.

Comment: jep, well not exactly. Iam currently figuring out in which folder the system looks. In the `es` or in the `dist` one.

Comment: This is a good reference: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#resolution-algorithm I think it will answer your questions.